# How can I get a list of links for questions with a specific tag?

Tags: support, api

Is there a programmatic interface for getting the questions with a specific tag?

The thing I have found was [archive.org/details/stackexchange](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

But this is not up-to-date.

I could write some scripts to get what I need but I wonder if there is some neat official API to do this. It is not clear whether [api.stackexchange.com](https://api.stackexchange.com/) is the way to go.

How can I get a list of questions with a specific tag?

Comment: We don't call them _labels_ but _tags_. You don't need an API, just access somewhere like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

Answer (score 3):

This is exactly what [the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/), [the *Stack Exchange Data Explorer* (SEDE)](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), and [the data dumps](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) are for.

- **Use the API for up to date, *daily*,** processing of small to medium numbers of posts (Max number of posts is 1 million per day (10,000 API calls with max pagesize of 100) ).
- Use SEDE to answer a great many "What if" questions.  But SEDE data can be up to a week old.
- Use the **data dumps for extensive offline analysis** on your own SQL server. The data is updated quarterly.
- Use [the *BigQuery* port of the data dumps](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/), to overcome some of the limits of SEDE (row size, timeout, API), with an online interface.  The data is only updated quarterly, though (same as the data dumps).
- Use a hybrid approach where your app loads and caches the data dump and then only uses the API to fetch activity since the last dump (or cache) date.

---

### For the API,

you would use [the `/questions` route][5], specifying tag(s).
**See [Looking for a beginner's tutorial to using the API][6]**.

Here is sample JavaScript code that you can run from the console of [decent modern browsers][7].  It returns the 5 most recently active economics questions, tagged `inflation`:

```js
fetch (
    'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?pagesize=5&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=inflation&site=economics&filter=!Pvz4gBt9fuC8jI)sZ7Hbtli6RDBLFE'
)
.then (function (response) {
    if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
    }
    throw new Error (`API problem: Error ${response.status}, ${response.statusText}`);
} )
.then (function (rJsn) {
    if (rJsn.backoff  ||  rJsn.error_id) {
        throw new Error (`From API: Backoff ${rJsn.backoff}, Error: ${rJsn.error_id}, ${rJsn.error_message}, ${rJsn.error_name}`);
    }
    console.log (`Quota remaining: ${rJsn.quota_remaining}; Items found: ${rJsn.items.length}`);

    let zQuestions = rJsn.items;
    console.log ("\nQuestion Titles\n---------------");
    for (let qst of zQuestions) {
        console.log (qst.title);
    }
} );
```

Note:

1. Your code should also include [a key][8].
2. [`backoff` is not necessarily an error][9]. Production code can wait the indicated interval and retry.

---

### For SEDE,

The query is simple, like [this one][10]:

```sql
SELECT
    q.Id AS [Post Link],
    q.LastActivityDate,
    q.Tags
FROM        Posts           q
INNER JOIN  PostTags        pt
ON          q.Id            = pt.PostId
INNER JOIN  Tags            t
ON          t.Id            = pt.TagId
WHERE       q.PostTypeId    = 1 -- questions
AND         t.TagName       IN ('inflation')
ORDER BY    q.LastActivityDate DESC
```

[5]: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=inflation&filter=!Pvz4gBt9fuC8jI)sZ7Hbtli6RDBLFE&site=economics&run=true
[6]: [Looking for a beginner's tutorial to using the API](https://stackapps.com/questions/4511/looking-for-a-beginners-tutorial-to-using-the-api)
[7]: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch
[8]: [How API Keys Work (FAQ)](https://stackapps.com/questions/67/how-api-keys-work)
[9]: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle
[10]: https://data.stackexchange.com/economics/query/638456/sample-simple-question-query-by-tag

Comment: backoff is not an error condition, right?

Comment: @rene, depends.  Yes, a production app should attempt to delay and retry on backoff.  But that is beyond the scope of this simple demo.  Note that the code did not call it an error, just gave it a critical alert level.

Comment: I assumed the throw would stop execution.

Comment: @rene, the throw *does* stop execution -- which is entirely appropriate in this case.  This is simplified demo code, not a production app. Keep in mind that a great many production API apps do not handle backoff well (or at all).  Even SmokeDetector didn't for the longest while.  The important thing for beginners is to not just keep hammering the API when backoff is received.

Comment: The API example here is an OK vanilla example, although it would probably be clearer and less distracting to simply link to [the API demo page](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#order=desc&sort=activity&tagged=inflation&filter=default&site=economics&run=true) in lieu of an example, where the response is clearly shown and the documentation is present and theoretically up to date. Also then you wouldn't have to get into side-discussions about whether or not you are e.g. handling backoff properly. Btw https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678 has a lot of good SEDE info.

Comment: @JasonC, the demo is already linked.  But, because the OP indicated that he already had seen the API livedocs, I included the simple code that anyone can run from their browser. .. I included the *minimal* code that both: (a) accomplished the OP's goal, and (b) shows the *minimum* handling of all the errors/states that so many developers overlook (and then open questions about).  I never expected to be called out for addressing backoff, when most of the API code out there overlooks it and/or gets it wrong. 8-)

Comment: @AwesomePoodles Huh, I thought they were, but I guess not. Not sure what I was thinking of.

Comment: @JasonC, No problémo.  It would've been nice if they were weekly (and also snarfed by BigQuery).